# How to mock useRouter parameters for react-hooks-testing-library?

Tags: react-hooks, react-testing-library, react-hooks-testing-library

I have a custom hook, which has structure of:

```
const urlHook = () => {
const router = useRouter();

const read = () => {
  return validate(router.query.param);
}

const write = (params) => {
  router.push(
    {
      query: {
        param: params,
      },
    },
    undefined,
    {shallow: true},
  )
}

const validate = (params) => {}
}
```

I want to test this hook using `react-hooks-testing-library` but I'm not sure how to setup for `router.query.param` to read values that I want or how to check if function `write()` will create correct url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mock entire hook - `jest.requireActual`:

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useParams: () => ({
    blogId: 'company1',
    articleId: 'blog1',
  }),
  useRouteMatch: () => ({ url: '/blog/blog1/article/article1' }),
}));
```

To mock history/routing state - MemoryRouter:

```
import {Route, MemoryRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

...

const renderWithRouter = ({children}) => (
  render(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['blogs/1']}>
      <Route path='blogs/:blogId'>
        {children}
      </Route>
    </MemoryRouter>
  )
)
```

Helpful example with explanations:
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/testing